# Converting date format of JXDatePicker to date type of mysql for storing it in database In java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have used JXDatePicker in my java application and I want to store its value in a MySQL database. The database value to be stored is of date type.

Here is my code:

```
final JXDatePicker dodc = new JXDatePicker(System.currentTimeMillis());
final SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date datedodc;

dodc.setBounds(250, 260, 150, 20);
    content.add(dodc);
    dodc.setForeground(BLACK);
    dodc.setBackground(WHITE);
    dodc.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    dodc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             datedodc = dodc.getDate();
            System.out.println(formater.format(dodc.getDate()));
        }
    });
```

If I print this value it gives the following output:

```
Feb 05 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

I want to store the date type value in mysql with the format: `yyyy-mm-dd`
How can I do it?

Eclipse gives me the following error when I try to store the values:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Feb 05 00:00:00 IST 2013,Mon Feb 18 00:00:00 IST 2013,'Gujju Enterprise',4,'faaf' at line 1

        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2934)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1616)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1708)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1350)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1266)
        at inwardRecord.save(inwardRecord.java:379)
        at inwardRecord.actionPerformed(inwardRecord.java:304)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Feb 05 00:00:00 IST 2013,Mon Feb 18 00:00:00 IST 2013,'Gujju Enterprise',4,'faaf' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
jXDatePicker1.setFormats(dateFormat);
DateFormat sysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
String date_to_store = sysDate.format(jXDatePicker1.getDate()).toString();
```

This will give you `jXDatePicker1` (declaration and initilization not included here) input as properly formatted String `date_to_store` output to store in mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateString = format.format(date.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach :

```
int selectedYear =  (int)  datePicker.getModel().getYear();
int selectedMonth = (int)  datePicker.getModel().getMonth();
int selectedDay = (int)  datePicker.getModel().getDay();

String selectedDate = selectedYear +"-"+selectedMonth+"-"+selectedDay;
```

You can now store the `selectedDate` in your database.